# Delphi dyn array char to string

Tags: массивы, delphi, строки

Кроме как перебором как реализовать?

```
Function ToString(ArrIn:Array of Char):string;  <<<Реализовать без цикла, возможно и без проверки окончания строки, но желательно с ним.
Var
  i:integer;    
Begin
  Result:='';
  For i:=0 to length(ArrIn)-2 do
   If (ArrIn[i]=#0 ) and (ArrIn[i+1]=#0 ) then Break else<<<<Найдено окончание строки
    Result:=Result+ArrIn[i];
End;

Var
  ar: array of char;
  s : String;
Begin
  SetLength(ar,100);
  FillChar(ar,100,#0);
  .......
  s:=ToString(ar);<<   Как реализовать?)
end.
```

Comment: Зы. массив заполняется юникодом, нужно верно определить окончание текста. все набивается в рад2. перебор массива поэлементно не предлогать.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, реализовать функцию ToString без использования цикла?

Comment: @DelphiM0ZG: думаю, с циклами :) ТС наверняка ищет встроенную функцию, но цикл тоже сойдёт.

Comment: Да, я имею ввиду как реализовать подобную фун-ю без использования цикла. встроеных не ищу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SetLength(ar, 100);
  FillChar(ar[0], 100, #49);
  s := StrPas(PChar(ar));
```

Обратите внимание:  `FillChar(ar[0], 100, #49)`, а не `FillChar(ar, 100, #49)`.

Ваш вариант испортит память.

**UPD0.** Да, хочу немного огорчить ТС. Данный способ тоже использует цикл. Вуаля:

```
@UStrFromPWChar:
00404BD0 31C9             xor ecx,ecx
00404BD2 85D2             test edx,edx
00404BD4 742D             jz $00404c03
00404BD6 52               push edx
00404BD7 663B0A           cmp cx,[edx]
00404BDA 7420             jz $00404bfc
00404BDC 663B4A02         cmp cx,[edx+$02]
00404BE0 7417             jz $00404bf9
00404BE2 663B4A04         cmp cx,[edx+$04]
00404BE6 740E             jz $00404bf6
00404BE8 663B4A06         cmp cx,[edx+$06]
00404BEC 7405             jz $00404bf3
00404BEE 83C208           add edx,$08
00404BF1 EBE4             jmp $00404bd7
00404BF3 83C202           add edx,$02
00404BF6 83C202           add edx,$02
00404BF9 83C202           add edx,$02
00404BFC 89D1             mov ecx,edx
00404BFE 5A               pop edx
00404BFF 29D1             sub ecx,edx
00404C01 D1E9             shr ecx,1
00404C03 E958FFFFFF       jmp @UStrFromPWCharLen
00404C08 C3               ret
```

Более того, мне не совсем ясно, как вы хотите отбрасывать хвост после `#0` без цикла. У процессора такой инструкции нет, значит кто-то должен взять и поочередно сравнить все символы с `#0`.

Comment: Можно уточнить по коду, после FillChar(ar[0], 100, #49) я получу строку длинной(всегда!) равную длинне ar, в случае заполнения массива #0 отработает ли данный код? и будет ли длинна строки(в случаях когда строка не весь массив заняла) меньше длинны массива?

Comment: для `FillChar(ar[0], 100, #0)` будет строка длиной 0.

Кстати в варианте с заполнением #0 Касперский сходит с ума )

Comment: Про касперского интересно, к счастью антивирусы на компе не стоят.
Но несовсем понятно по какой причине будет работать вариант с заполнением массива символом "1"...
Вот что мне сказал всезнающий яндекс"
Преобразовывает строку с нулевым окончанием в строку стиля Pascal. Режим: Windows, Real, Protected. Замечания: StrPas преобразовывает строку Str в строку стиля Pascal."
В любом случае StrPas именно та альтернатива CopyMem которую и хотелось получить, принимаю ответ.

Comment: Жаль, а так хотелось красивого решения....

Comment: > к счастью антивирусы на компе не стоят  
о как

Comment: Досих пор считаю что антивиры - зло, вирусы я и ручками покиляю, а то что заразят всегда можно перекомпилить\восстановить из бэкапа Оо

Comment: Заразят-то ладно. А вот то что вы можете успеть разнести вирусы клиентам/коллегам, или троянцы могут упереть ваши пароли от облаков, это должно беспокоить.

Answer (score 2):

[украдено](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281856/convert-array-of-char-to-string)

```
function ArrayToString(const a: array of Char): string;
begin
  if Length(a)>0 then
    SetString(Result, PChar(@a[0]), Length(a))
  else
    Result := '';
end;
```

Comment: Неподходит, загляние в исполнение процедуры SetString, там цикл.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyString := String(MyDynArray); // без обреза хвоста после #0
```

или

```
MyPChar := PChar(MyDynArray);  // с обрезом
MyString := PChar(MyDynArray); // с обрезом
```

П. С. :
String - это и есть динамический массив символов.
PChar (как и массивы) есть указателем на начало данных. Конец строки обозначаются нулевым байтом (#0)

пример

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyString: string;
  MyPChar: PChar;
  MyDynArr: array of Char;
begin
  SetLength(MyDynArr, 10);
  FillChar(Pointer(MyDynArr)^, Length(MyDynArr) * SizeOf(Char), #0);
  MyDynArr[0] := '5'; // FillChar не подходит так как Char займает 2 байты (начиная с Delphi 2009

  MyPChar := PChar(MyDynArr);
  MyString := PChar(MyDynArr);
  MyString := string(MyDynArr);

  ShowMessage(MyPChar + '|' + MyString);
end;
```

Comment: Спаиб за ответ, но уже все реализовано и скорость устраивает, и пы.сы при таком подходе возможны глюки, обрезания по факту не произойдет, просто при обращении к строке будет выводится инф-ия до первого #0, а при следующей перетасовке MyDynArray без перезаполнения #0 возможно что часть старой строки попадет в текущую) и да, попробуйте такие фокусе не в D7 провернуть а в Rad2, много наслушаетесь от компилятора)

Comment: Если использовать MyPChar то да, а если MyString - то это уже копия.

>>такие фокусе не в D7 провернуть а в Rad2, много наслушаетесь от компилятора  
у меня Delphi XE3 не матерится (добавил пример)
  
  
Хотя если все и так работает тогда зачем что то менять? Удачи)